# Explorer Search does not work

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-explorer, search

Look at how I can't find a file that is clearly in the folder as I'm looking at it.

Folder: `C:\Users\dasbest\Documents\Portable Apps\FL Studio 8\Plugins\VST-old`
Filename: `Prophet-V2.dll`
Search pattern: `prophet`

[image]

[image: cannot find file with explorer search]

I have rebuilt the search index, used the troubleshooter for fixing search and have restarted the windows search service. I'm using Windows 8.1 64 bit.

Comment: Your screenshot does not show you searching for anything ... there is nothing in the search box ...

Comment: The screenshot does show me searching for stuff. http://imgur.com/a/SBWvK

Comment: Did you try `prophet*`?

Comment: Although Windows Search has seen significant improvement, I still find it slow, unreliable and counterintuitive; separate and more traditional search utilities still suit me better. I can suggest File [Locator Lite a.k.a. Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorlite) as a valid alternative.

Comment: It works now for some reason and I don't know why as I didn't make any changes to search or explorer.